# Keep gettinga column of <NA> in my dataframe where characters should be in R?

Tags: r, string, dataframe

So I'm trying to parse together two values to create a character ID for each value in a dataframe in R. This data frame has a letter for a group the value is in, and then the ID number within that group. I want the format of ID 1 in Group A to be "1:A", so I created a new column in my df as follows:

```
df = data.frame(FirstID = numeric(), SecondID = numeric, Distance = numeric(), CharID = character())
```

And then I loop through my data and fill the data frame.

```
df[counter, 1] <- #value
df[counter, 2] <- #value
df[counter, 3] <- #value
numChar <- as.character(#Data$ID[i])
df[counter, 4] <- paste(numChar, "A", sep = ":", collapse = NULL)
```

But apparently, when I try to run this function, I get 50 warnings saying

Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "1:A") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
...
Any ideas on what I may be doing wrong here?

Comment: As the warning message implies, you have `factor` class column.  Convert it to `character` first

Comment: Wait, even if i declared the column as a character() column in my df declaration?

Comment: You may need `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`

Comment: Oh that fixed it. Thank you! Thought that was FALSE by default.